# Seeing unexpected behavior when using lxml to parse HTML

Tags: python, python-3.x, lxml

I'm seeing some unexpected behavior when using [lxml](http://lxml.de/) to parse the following HTML. Here's my Python 3 code:

```
    from lxml import etree, html

    s = """
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title></title>
      </head>
      <body>
      <strong>ABC</strong>"<" and ">"
      </body>
    </html>
    """

    doc = etree.ElementTree(html.fromstring(s))
    print(etree.tostring(doc, pretty_print=True, encoding="unicode"))
```

Here's the output I get:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title/>
      </head>
      <body>
      <strong>ABC</strong>""
      </body>
    </html>
```

Is there something I'm missing or doing wrong? Or is this a bug in  lxml?

Comment: What are you expecting?  I get a similar but slightly different output from Python2.

Comment: I would expect the output to be the same as in the input.

The parser doesn't appear to handle the less-than and greater-than signs after the <strong> tag correctly.

Comment: James Sun, okay, in that case I'm seeing the same kind of thing as you.  It must be to do with the apparent bad tag.

Answer (score 0):

1. A literal left angle bracket (`<`) needs to be represented (escaped) as `&lt;`. An unescaped `<` that is not the first character of an actual tag, such as `<strong>`, will disrupt parsing.
2. `etree.tostring()` uses the rules of XML. If you want `<title></title>` instead of `<title/>` in the output, use `html.tostring()`.